# What does gist of a texture really mean?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

Could someone please explain me what is exactly a gist feature vector of a image represent ? How may features from a image can we get from a GIST feature extraction ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read [the original paper](http://cvcl.mit.edu/papers/oliva04.pdf)? There's probably not a much better way of explaining the gist of the gist (so to speak) than reading the papers themselves.

Comment: could someone please explain me in more simple terms

Comment: I am wondering if there is an acronym for GIST, like for SIFT? Maybe gradient information (scales and orientations)?